# Ansible Playbook to deploy HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T "

Tags: ansible

I'm having issues adding timestamps for root's history to /.bashrc with an ansible playbook to a list of servers.

My main issue is the syntax here

```yaml
---
- name: history timestamps
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  shell: export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
  register: shell_output
  loop:
    - 1

- debug: var=shell_output
```

Answer (score 3):

Take closer look at the shell script you're trying to run: you're trying to write the output of `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T "'` to your `.bashrc` file. What does `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T "'` output?

```
$ export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T "'
```

The answer is it doesn't output anything: you're just setting an environment variable.

You could write your script like this...

```yaml
- name: history timestamps
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  shell: |
    cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOF
    export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
    EOF
```

(note that I've removed the unnecessary `loop` option)

...but normally if you're trying to write a line to a file you would
use the `lineinfile` module:

```yaml
- name: history timestamps
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  lineinfile:
    path: ~/.bashrc
    line: export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
```

Lastly, note that `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is a bash local variable; you don't
actually need to `export` it to the environment:

```yaml
- name: history timestamps
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  lineinfile:
    path: ~/.bashrc
    line: HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
```